# Graphic glitch after interrupted apt upgrade?

Tags: updates, apt, graphics

I'm new to this forum, so sorry for any mistakes..
Today I booted my Elementary OS into this (see the screenshot). Blurred or missing texts, no text in menus... But pages and menus a rendering correctly in Google Chrome and in Steam.

The problem might be corrupted apt upgrade process. Yesterday I experienced a power blackout when apt was finishing the upgrade process. One of the packages were some mesa packages, but it seemed almost finished, just setting things up.
I tried to re-install them and reboot, but nothing happened.

However, before the blackout, I also installed libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 trying to solve a minor glitch in Trine game. Later, after the reboot, I tried to remove libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 and install it back again, but neither helped.

How can I identify the real cause of the problem and solve it? I can provide you any information you ask for, but I have no idea where to start.

This is the mentioned apt upgrade:

```
Start-Date: 2018-02-08  22:56:41 Commandline: apt upgrade Requested-By: drnec (1000) Install: libboost-locale1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1, automatic), libboost-thread1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1, automatic), fonts-liberation2:amd64 (2.00.1-5~16.04.1~lo4, automatic) Upgrade: libreoffice-style-breeze:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libreoffice-math:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libgles2-mesa:amd64 (1:18.1~git180129151100.0347a83~x~padoka0, 1:18.1~git180208124100.e843667~x~padoka0), libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.89+git1801241146.1cc1774~x~padoka0,
2.4.89+git1802081214.fa35b51~x~padoka0), libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.89+git1801241146.1cc1774~x~padoka0,
2.4.89+git1802081214.fa35b51~x~padoka0), libreoffice-gtk2:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libparted2:amd64 (3.2-15, 3.2-15ubuntu0.1), libreoffice-core:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (1:18.1~git180129151100.0347a83~x~padoka0, 1:18.1~git180208124100.e843667~x~padoka0), libglapi-mesa:i386 (1:18.1~git180129151100.0347a83~x~padoka0, 1:18.1~git180208124100.e843667~x~padoka0), libreoffice-style-oxygen:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libreoffice-style-human:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), papirus-icon-theme:amd64 (20180204-2173+pkg18~ubuntu16.04.1, 20180207-2186+pkg18~ubuntu16.04.1), libxatracker2:amd64 (1:18.1~git180129151100.0347a83~x~padoka0, 1:18.1~git180208124100.e843667~x~padoka0), libreoffice-style-hicontrast:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), flashplugin-installer:amd64 (28.0.0.137ubuntu0.16.04.1, 28.0.0.161ubuntu0.16.04.1), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (1:18.1~git180129151100.0347a83~x~padoka0, 1:18.1~git180208124100.e843667~x~padoka0), libreoffice-style-sifr:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), python3-uno:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libparted-fs-resize0:amd64 (3.2-15, 3.2-15ubuntu0.1), libapparmor1:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.7, 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8), libgbm1:amd64 (1:18.1~git180129151100.0347a83~x~padoka0, 1:18.1~git180208124100.e843667~x~padoka0), adapta-gtk-theme:amd64 (3.93.0.110-0ubuntu1~xenial1, 3.93.0.113-0ubuntu1~xenial1), libreoffice-style-galaxy:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libreoffice-base-core:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.89+git1801241146.1cc1774~x~padoka0,
2.4.89+git1802081214.fa35b51~x~padoka0), libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.89+git1801241146.1cc1774~x~padoka0,
2.4.89+git1802081214.fa35b51~x~padoka0), libreoffice-style-elementary:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libapparmor-perl:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.7, 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8), oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms:amd64 (0.201802042116~ubuntu16.04.1,
0.201802072245~ubuntu16.04.1), chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 (64.0.3282.119-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 64.0.3282.140-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (1:18.1~git180129151100.0347a83~x~padoka0, 1:18.1~git180208124100.e843667~x~padoka0), ure:amd64 (5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libreoffice-writer:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libreoffice-common:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), parted:amd64 (3.2-15, 3.2-15ubuntu0.1), libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.89+git1801241146.1cc1774~x~padoka0,
2.4.89+git1802081214.fa35b51~x~padoka0), libdrm2:i386 (2.4.89+git1801241146.1cc1774~x~padoka0,
2.4.89+git1802081214.fa35b51~x~padoka0), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (1:18.1~git180129151100.0347a83~x~padoka0, 1:18.1~git180208124100.e843667~x~padoka0), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (1:18.1~git180129151100.0347a83~x~padoka0, 1:18.1~git180208124100.e843667~x~padoka0), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (1:18.1~git180129151100.0347a83~x~padoka0, 1:18.1~git180208124100.e843667~x~padoka0), libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (1:18.1~git180129151100.0347a83~x~padoka0, 1:18.1~git180208124100.e843667~x~padoka0), fonts-opensymbol:amd64 (2:102.10+LibO5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 2:102.10+LibO6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.89+git1801241146.1cc1774~x~padoka0,
2.4.89+git1802081214.fa35b51~x~padoka0), libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.89+git1801241146.1cc1774~x~padoka0,
2.4.89+git1802081214.fa35b51~x~padoka0), apparmor:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.7, 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8), uno-libs3:amd64 (5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libreoffice-style-tango:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.89+git1801241146.1cc1774~x~padoka0,
2.4.89+git1802081214.fa35b51~x~padoka0), libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.89+git1801241146.1cc1774~x~padoka0,
2.4.89+git1802081214.fa35b51~x~padoka0), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (1:18.1~git180129151100.0347a83~x~padoka0, 1:18.1~git180208124100.e843667~x~padoka0), libreoffice-calc:amd64 (1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1, 1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo7), libdrm-common:amd64 (2.4.89+git1801241146.1cc1774~x~padoka0,
2.4.89+git1802081214.fa35b51~x~padoka0) End-Date: 2018-02-08  23:00:56
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be a result of broken packages because of the power loss during the update process.

You can try this (in Terminal):

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Once you've done that, update and then upgrade using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Once you've done the above comment back with the results.

Good Luck!!!